# Hashmap comparison

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two hashmaps. This is just example of 2 hashmaps, there can be n hashmaps.

They look like this

```
HashMap A = [(a, 23),(b,25),(c,43),(d,34)]
HashMap B = [(a, 32),(b,52),(d,55)]
```

Now I want to compare these hashmaps in such a way so that I can put the missing key of 'c' into HashMap B with value as 0.

How can I do that? Remember there can be n HashMaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the "target" HashMap the one that will get the missing keys and "sources" each of the others.  For each key in each source, if the target does not contain the key then associate the zero with that key in the target:

```
for (Map<String,Number> source : sources) {
  for (String key : source.keySet() ) {
    if (!target.containsKey(key)) {
      target.put(key, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you want to ensure that *all* maps have all keys from all other maps then you should first compute the entire set of keys and add the missing ones to each map:

```
Set<String> allKeys = new HashSet<String>();
for (Map<String,Number> map : allHashMaps) {
  allKeys.addAll(map.keySet());
}
for (Map<String,Number> map : allHashMaps) {
  for (String key : allKeys) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
      map.put(key, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Both solutions perform at O(n*k) where `n` is the number of maps and `k` is the average number of keys in each map.

Comment: In the second case, so that we don't have N^2 calls to `containsKey` (which would effectively make your function O(N^2)), I'd rather just compute the key-set difference for each map in question. The function is still O(N^2) (since the differencing is O(N) and it's executed N times), but, the constant factor is likely to be lower.

Comment: How do I do this if I am getting these hashmaps in a loop from other object?

Comment: Ah true, `Set#removeAll` will perform at the smaller of the two set size constants, but with the same big-oh.  If it makes a difference in reality depends, of course, on the reality of the data =)

Comment: But on second thought, computing the key-set difference requires you to create a new set containing all keys from which to remove each map's existing keys (so as not to mutate the `allKeys` set).  This additional step adds constant-time work of the size of allKeys, so I don't think it actually gains you anything.

Answer (score 3):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has something that could help you here:

```
Map<K, V> a = ...
Map<K, V> b = ...
MapDifference<K, V> difference = Maps.difference(a, b);
```

A [MapDifference](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html) then allows you to check various things about the difference of the two maps, such as what entries the left `Map` has that the right doesn't and vice versa.

If you wanted to make sure that there aren't any entries in map `a` that `b` doesn't have, you could do something like this:

```
b.putAll(difference.entriesOnlyOnLeft());
```

How you handle a series of maps depends on exactly what you need to do with them, which you didn't really explain... but you could just loop through them doing the above with every pair of maps to ensure that the last map has at least every entry that is in every other map, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `A.keySet().removeAll(B.keySet())` which will give you all the items in A that are not in B

Comment: modifications to the keySet also modify the underlying map; it might not be desirable (or even allowable) to modify `A`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> void mergeKeys(Map<T, Integer> target, Map<T, ?>... sources) {
    Set<T> newKeys = new HashSet<T>();
    for (Map<T, ?> source : sources)
        newKeys.addAll(source.keySet());
    newKeys.removeAll(target.keySet());
    for (T key : newKeys)
        target.put(key, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Key> keys = new HashSet<Key>(/* if you have any perspective on size, could put it here */);
for (Map<Key, ?> map : n-maps) keys.addAll(map.keySet());
for (Map<Key, ?> map : n-maps) for (Key k : keys) if(!map.containsKey(k)) map.put(k, defaultObject);
```

where `n-maps` is an `Iterable` or array of your maps, and the `defaultObject` is whatever default you want to put in there.

There are some sensible optimization routes, like comparing the size of the `keys` set to that of the target `map`, which would allow you to branch into a couple of sensible categories: the same size, very close to 0 or `keys.size()`, or otherwise.